# AMD GPU not being used by Debian

Tags: debian, drivers, gpu, amd-graphics, amd

I'm running Debian 10 with kernel 5.10 via buster backports. The installed driver for amd is amdgpu and the output of `dmesg` from my understanding tells me the driver is being
recognized,

```
[    2.774224] [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
[    2.774409] amdgpu: Topology: Add CPU node
[    2.774596] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Trusted Memory Zone (TMZ) feature not supported
[    2.792960] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Fetched VBIOS from ATRM
[    2.792962] amdgpu: ATOM BIOS: BR64533.001
[    2.811910] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/polaris12_k_mc.bin
[    2.811918] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VRAM: 2048M 0x000000F400000000 - 0x000000F47FFFFFFF (2048M used)
[    2.811919] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GART: 256M 0x000000FF00000000 - 0x000000FF0FFFFFFF
[    2.811996] [drm] amdgpu: 2048M of VRAM memory ready
[    2.811997] [drm] amdgpu: 3072M of GTT memory ready.
[    2.812695] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/polaris12_pfp_2.bin
[    2.812704] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/polaris12_me_2.bin
[    2.812712] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/polaris12_ce_2.bin
[    2.812721] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/polaris12_rlc.bin
[    2.812776] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/polaris12_mec_2.bin
[    2.812832] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/polaris12_mec2_2.bin
[    2.813340] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/polaris12_sdma.bin
[    2.813348] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/polaris12_sdma1.bin
[    2.813383] amdgpu: hwmgr_sw_init smu backed is polaris10_smu
[    2.813465] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/polaris12_uvd.bin
[    2.814530] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/polaris12_vce.bin
[    2.815130] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/polaris12_k_smc.bin
[    3.051566] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SE 2, SH per SE 1, CU per SH 5, active_cu_number 10
[    3.055642] [drm] Initialized amdgpu 3.40.0 20150101 for 0000:03:00.0 on minor 1
```

and `lshw -c video` shows both the integrated and dedicated GPU

```
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:130 memory:c1000000-c1ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: c0
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:131 memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c01fffff ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c2300000-c233ffff memory:c2340000-c235ffff
```

However when I run `glxinfo -B` or  `DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo -B`  the output is

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: VMware, Inc. (0xffffffff)
    Device: llvmpipe (LLVM 7.0, 256 bits) (0xffffffff)
    Version: 18.3.6
    Accelerated: no
    Video memory: 15817MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 3.3
    Max compat profile version: 3.1
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.0
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 7.0, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.3.6
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
 
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 18.3.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)
 
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 18.3.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
```

I have tried running programs that could use the GPU as well but they seem to keep using the VMWare llvmpipe gpu, the output of `radeontop` always shows up as 0%. How do I get my machine to use amdgpu?

Comment: If this is a VMware virtual machine, only the `llvmpipe` GPU is actually connected to the VMware's virtual KVM console. Are you trying to use the AMD GPU to enhance graphics performance on the virtual KVM? If so, what does `xrandr --listproviders` say? A more typical use of add-on GPUs in a VM would be GPU computing,  I think.

Comment: No this is running on baremetal, ```xrandr --listproviders``` gives me ```Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x6b cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 3 outputs: 4 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
Provider 1: id: 0x44 cap: 0xf, Source Output, Sink Output, Source Offload, Sink Offload crtcs: 5 outputs: 0 associated providers: 0 name:Radeon 550X Series @ pci:0000:03:00.0
``` I have tried changing the priority order but it gives me ```X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution and posting just incase someone else runs into the same issue. The problem for this arose due to the mesa library being outdated in Debian buster for the specific cpu I was using (10th Gen). Updating to Debian 11 or downloading mesa libraries from Debian 11 should fix the issue.